# Amazon S3 multipart upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a .bak file(24gb) to amazon s3 using multipart upload low-level API approach in Java. I was able to write the file successfully but the time it took was around 7-8 hours. I want to know what is the average/ideal time to upload a file of such a big size, is the time it took is expected or it can be improved? If there is a scope for improvement than what could be the approach?

Comment: This probably has more to do with **your server's** isp's upload speed than anything else. Have you checked what that is at?

Comment: @JoeLissner Yes it is 13mbs

Comment: Assuming it was always a constant 13mbs and never interrupted, it would take 4-5 hours. My guess is that it isn't always dedicating the full 13mbs to the fileupload.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using default settings of Transfer Manager, then for multipart uploads, the [DEFAULT_MINIMUM_UPLOAD_PART_SIZE](https://github.com/Widen/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManagerConfiguration.java#L44) is 5MB which is too low for a 24GB file. This essentially means that you'll end up having thousands of small part uploaded to s3. Since each part is uploaded by a different worker thread, your application will spend too much time in Network communication. This will not give you optimal uploading speed.

You must increase the minimum upload part size to be between 100MB to 500 MB. Use this setting : [setMinimumUploadPartSize](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManagerConfiguration.html#setMinimumUploadPartSize-long-)

Official Documentation for setting MinimumUploadPartSize :

> Decreasing the minimum part size will cause multipart uploads to be split into a larger number of smaller parts. Setting this value too low can have a negative effect on transfer speeds since it will cause extra latency and network communication for each part.

I am certain you'll see improvement in upload throughput by tuning this setting if you are currently using default settings. Let me know if this improves the throughput.

Happy Uploading !!!